# like a search engine

Tags: java, regex, object, match

I have a list of objects that contains names of movies for a class called `Video`:

```
Video v1 = new Video("The Shawshank Redemption", "Frank Darabont", "Drama", "9.2*", 49.99, true);
Video v2 = new Video("The Godfather", "Francis Ford Coppola", "Crime, Drama", "9.2*", 49.99, true);
Video v3 = new Video("The Godfather: Part II", "Francis Ford Coppola", "Crime, Drama", "9*", 48.99, true);
Video v4 = new Video("The Dark Knight", "Christopher Nolan", "Action, Crime, Drama", "9*", 48.99, false);
Video v5 = new Video("Pulp Fiction ", "Quentin Tarantino", "Crime, Thriller, Drama", "8.9*", 47.99, true);
```

I need to get the user to input the name or parts of a name (containing at least 3 characters) and then print the movies that match the user's input and I'm not really sure how to do it in an easy way.

Any ideas?
This is my full code

```
    class Video
{
    String name, director, type, rating;
    Double price;
    boolean borrowed;
    String borrowedTrue;
    Video(String n, String d, String t, String r, Double p, boolean b)
    {

        name = n;
        director = d;
        type = t;
        rating = r;
        price = p;
        borrowed = b;

        if(b == true)
        {
            borrowedTrue = "Yes";

        }
        else if(b == false)
        {
            borrowedTrue = "No";

        }


    }
    public void display()
    {

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("******************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Director: "+director);
        System.out.println("Type: "+type);
        System.out.println("Rating: "+rating);
        System.out.println("Prince: "+price);
        System.out.println("Borrowed: " +borrowedTrue);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("******************************");
    }
}
```

for the class and i have this for objects

```
    import java.util.*;
class TestVideo
{

    static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Video v1 = new Video("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont","Drama","9.2*",49.99,true);
        Video v2 = new Video("The Godfather","Francis Ford Coppola","Crime,Drama","9.2*",49.99,true);
        Video v3 = new Video("The Godfather: Part II","Francis Ford Coppola","Crime,Drama","9*",48.99,true);
        Video v4 = new Video("The Dark Knight","Christopher Nolan","Action,Crime,Drama","9*",48.99,false);
        Video v5 = new Video("Pulp Fiction ","Quentin Tarantino","Crime,Thriller,Drama","8.9*",47.99,true);
        Video v6 = new Video("12 Angry Men","Sidney Lumet","Drama","8.9*",47.99,true);
        Video v7 = new Video("The Good, the Bad and the Ugly","Sergio Leone","Western","8.9*",47.99,false);
        Video v8 = new Video("Schindler's List","Steven Spielberg","Bography,History,Drama","8.9*",47.99,false);
        Video v9 = new Video("The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King","Peter Jackson"," Peter Jackson","8.9*",47.99,true);
        Video v10 = new Video("Fight Club","David Fincher","Drama","8.9*",47.99,false);
        Video v11 = new Video("The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"," Peter Jackson"," Peter Jackson","8.8*",46.99,true);
        Video v12 = new Video("Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back","Irvin Kershner","Action,Adventure,Fanstasy","8.8*",46.99,true);
        Video v13 = new Video("Forrest Gump ","Robert Zemeckis","Romance,Drama","8.8*",46.99,false);
        Video v14 = new Video("Inception","Christopher Nolan","Action,Mystery,Sci-Fi","8.8*",47.99,false);
        Video v15 = new Video("The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers","Peter Jackson","Adventure,Fantasy","8.8*",45.99,false);
        Video v16 = new Video("Interstellar","Christopher Nolan","Adventure,Sci-Fi","8.8*",44.99,false);
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the movie");
        String matchName =user_input.next();
        if (matchName.matchesIgnoreCase("[the]*"))
        {
            v1.display();
            v2.display();
            // i have to manually search for any videos which name contains 'the' 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No match");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't know of any easy ways, then try doing it a non-easy way. Regardless, the important thing is that you first try. Then if you're still stuck,  you can come here with a much better more specific question as well as your code attempt.

Comment: Please don't write code in comments. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing your Video instances in a class implementing `java.util.List`, then a simple algorithm to accomplish this would be to search through the list and compare the search string passed by the user to the name field of your video.  I would read the javadocs on the String methods, like [`startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)).

For instance, presuming

```
// minimum functionality needed for example
public class Video{
    private String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void printDetails(){
        // some method that prints the movie details
    }
}
```

and you have your list, perhaps as a field of an enclosing class:

```
// Somewhere relevant in your code
List<Video> videos = new ArrayList<Video>();

// add your examples to the list
videos.add(v1);
videos.add(v2);
videos.add(v3);
videos.add(v4);
videos.add(v5);
```

This method would solve your problem:

```
public void printNames(String query){
    if(query.length() < 3){
        // report an error, with an exception or print statement
        System.out.println("Search query must be at least 3 characters.");
    }
    for(Video v : videos){
        if(v.getName().startsWith(query)){
            v.printDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I might suggest using a `StringBuilder` to build your return String, then print that.  Or, return a list of matching videos and manipulate them some other way.